# VBA code to delete duplicate rows that's already located in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to find a way to delete duplicate rows that is already located in another sheet. Both sheets have the same amount of columns(9).

Sheet 2 has a header(data starts row 2) and is the one that I need to keep the data in. Typically I can have about 100 rows in this sheet.

Sheet 1 is the one that I'm looking to delete the duplicated rows. (header starts on row 2 and data in row 3).

Is it possible to do this and not delete the headers sheet 1?

Comment: Are the columns the same in Sheet 1 and Sheet 2? Is there a common column between both sheets based on which you can say that a row in Sheet 1 is duplicated in Sheet 2?

Comment: Please share the code you have tried, screenshots of your worksheets, and some sample data as text. Also, explain what identifies a row to be deleted (e.g. the value (e.g. a unique ID) in column `A`).

Comment: @zedfoxus Both sheets have the same number of columns and same header titles. the data that is common  is in Colum D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Delete Matching Rows

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

```vb
Sub DeleteMatchingRows()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim srg As Range
    
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set srg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim drg As Range
    
    With dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set drg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 2).Offset(2)
    End With
    
    Dim drIndexes:
    drIndexes = Application.Match(drg.Columns(4), srg.Columns(4), 0)
    
    If Application.Count(drIndexes) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No matches found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim durg As Range, r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(drIndexes, 1)
        If IsNumeric(drIndexes(r, 1)) Then
            If durg Is Nothing Then
                Set durg = drg.Rows(r)
            Else
                Set durg = Union(durg, drg.Rows(r))
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    durg.Delete xlShiftUp
    
    MsgBox "Matching rows deleted.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```